# Setting up GNS3 lab

Tags: networking

I have a Kubuntu 14.04 OS, and I'm taking an on-line course on networking fundamentals.  I'm trying to set up a GNS3 lab that would enable me to use a Cisco IOSvL2 appliance.  Is that possible on my machine?  I have installed GNS3, but it looks like I cannot install GNS3 VMware.  It seems like I should be able to install VMware Workstation 12.5, but that's not working either.  I downloaded workstation, and it appears in my downloads, both as a .exe file, and as a .bundle.  I have root access, but when I type sudo chmod +x with the file name, I get a message stating "no such file or directory".  Also, here is part 2 of my question: my understanding is that I don't need VMware if I use a local dynamips implementation.  When I try to do that on the GNS3 set-up wizard, it wants to import an IOS image.  I have downloaded some IOS images from my VIRL account, but when I browse, nothing appears in the menu to import.  I appreciate any help. Thanks!